# .net WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I want to save images to client side using WCF service. We have a dynamic image generated at every 10 seconds from a client server. Can we read that url using WCF service and pass the image or byte buffer of that image, so that user can save it on local drive. We have a XMl file which provide the image url.

Can we use some other technique to get the images from the server at regular interval?

Thanks.
PAl

Comment: I am not sure what you really mean to do.  Do you want to save an image on client pc at regular interval? Send a file to the user when they click something? or Get an image at regular interval from a server and save it on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Using a timer, you can send your images via email as often as you want.  Also, you cannot initiate a WCF request from the server, but if your client poles the server regularly it can download the image files.